# Is it possible that BeautifulSoup can not parse a table in html documents?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here an example of the code I used to scraping the table:

```py
with open ('text.txt', 'w') as algroo:
    for row in RoOtbody.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            algroo.write(cell.text)
        algroo.write('\n')
```

I already used Selenium and requests to extract the outer html from the webpage. I also tried to use html.parser and lxml.

The html looks like this:

```
<tr class="table">
                     <td class="table" valign="top">
                        <p class="tbl-hdr">HS heading</p>
                     </td>
                     <td class="table" valign="top">
                        <p class="tbl-hdr">Desccription of product</p>
                     </td>
                     <td class="table" colspan="2" valign="top">
                        <p class="tbl-hdr">Working or processing, carried out on non-originating
materials, which confers originating status</p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
```

The problem is that when I open the txt file, all the cells elements are in a single column like the one below, literaly:

HS heading

Desccription of product

Working or processing, carried out on non-originating materials, which confers originating status

In all the tutorials I watched and read, they should be in the same row, like this:

HS headingDesccription of productWorking or processing, carried out on non-originating materials, which confers originating status

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? What does your code look like?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Well, the html is a table embedded in a document of an European Union treaty and it is quite long. My code looks like this: ```with open ('text.txt', 'w') as algroo:
    for row in RoOtbody.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            algroo.write(cell.text)
        algroo.write('\n') ```

Comment: @kaya3, I already have. The problem is that is quite difficult to put the html document in the question and, about the code, I wrote it in a comment

Comment: Try editing the HTML to remove the parts that are not necessary for reproducing the problem. Each time you remove something, check if the problem still exists. This should help you narrow down what's causing the problem, and if it doesn't, then you'll have something small enough to put in the question.

Comment: Thanks @kaya3. I've currently edited the post. Is it possible to make it public again? I really need to solve this problem.

Comment: That looks a lot better - if you include the expected output then I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks. I will work on it. I might not be able to fix it soon, though. I'm sorry

Comment: because you get text from `td` (not from `p`) so it may have `'\n'` at the end (which is in `td`) so later `write()` puts it in separated lines. You should use `.strip()` to remove it. But writing this way you get all as one string in one line. Maybe it would be better to get all values in list and use module `csv` to correctly create lines with comma separated data.

Comment: @furas, as I know, but maybe I got it wrong, either write() and strip() should put the content as one string in one line.

About the csv module, shouldn't it be the same? To make it as text file and then change it into a csv?

Comment: if text has `'\n` then write will write it in file and next text will be in new line. Using `strip()` is standard method to remove it - `algroo.write(cell.text.strip())` (normally you have to assign result to variable `text = text.strip()`). As for CSV, it is text file but columns are separated by comma `,` (or other char) so it is easier to recognize which text is in which column. You could put `,` manually but there are 2 commas in one of text so you would create row in 5 instead of 3 columns. `csv` would care of this and it would have no problem to read it again as 3 columns.

Comment: @furas, thanks for the strip() advice. Actually I've tried that before unsuccessfully, because I wrote it in the wrong place. Thanks also for the advice about the csv! I'll try to scrap everything directly in csv

Comment: @kaya3, if I may ask you an advice, I found that inside some cells there are nested tables and I'm having difficulties in extrapolating them. Should I write another question, or edit this one?

Comment: Better to ask another question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''<tr class="table">
                     <td class="table" valign="top">
                        <p class="tbl-hdr">HS heading</p>
                     </td>
                     <td class="table" valign="top">
                        <p class="tbl-hdr">Desccription of product</p>
                     </td>
                     <td class="table" colspan="2" valign="top">
                        <p class="tbl-hdr">Working or processing, carried out on non-originating
materials, which confers originating status</p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
tr = doc.tr # get first tr
print (tr.text)
print (tr.getText(' '))
tds = tr.tds # get all td
for td in tds:
  print (td.text)
```